# Is there a select to determine if I'm currently connected to an Oracle CDB or PDB?

Tags: oracle

Is there a select to determine if I'm currently connected to an Oracle CDB or PDB?

Comment: "The best way" depends in part on your client interface. What are you using - SQL\*Plus? SQL Developer? Toad? "The best way" in one may not even make sense in the other(s).

Comment: Just the sql statement to be used in (for example) SQL*Plus

Comment: Well - as I just showed in my answer, in SQL\*Plus you can use a SQL query, but you can also use a `SHOW` command (which is a SQL\*Plus command, it is not an SQL statement). That is exactly why I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a general solution, using a query.

Each connection has a connection id. The id is 1 for the `CDB` and 2 for `PDB$SEED`, and >=3 for other connections. (It's 0 for the entire multitenant database.) So:

```
select case sys_context('USERENV', 'CON_ID') 
            when '1' then 'CDB' else 'PDB' end
       as cdb_or_pdb
from   dual;
```

In specific user interfaces, you can use shortcuts. For example, in SQL*Plus:

```
show con_id
```

If it's 1 you are in the CDB, otherwise in a PDB.

Answer (score 0):

This will check if you are connected to a CDB, or a PDB or a NON_CDB

select
case
when (select VIEW_NAME from all_views where view_name='V_$CONTAINERS')='V_$CONTAINERS' then
case sys_context('USERENV', 'CON_ID') when '1' then 'CDB' else 'PDB' end
else 'NONCDB'
end
as cdb
from dual;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).